# how to add a `preview` action to resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I am looking for the right approach to include a `preview` action between `new` and `create` actions.
Let's assume I have the following:

```
resources :users
```

By default, when the form is submitted:

- if `new`, call `create` action;
- if `edit`, call `update` action.

In this way, I can use the same form (partial) for `new` and `create`, which is great!

How can I configure the resources to include a `preview` between actions. I mean, forcing `new` to call `preview` and then `preview` to call `create`.

I could add a new route/action and point the form for that action, however the same form cannot be used for `new` and `edit`.

There is a way to configure the resources to do that?

Comment: There is no way to configure the resources to do that, because 'resources' it's just routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this railscast: [multibutton form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form), it shows a form with both a 'preview' and 'submit' button, maybe that's something you might want to do.

By the way, couldn't you use the same form by passing locals to the partial? For example:

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: dynamic_path do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= render 'form', dynamic_path: profile_preview_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have several ways to do this:

1. you change the url of the form to your `preview` action (for which you have to add a route).
2. you use your create action for preview and create:
   i.e. you add a parameter (like ':go_to_preview') to the form submit request. if you find it in the controller you render `preview`.
   when the user wants to confirm the preview, you submit the data again (without that parameter) and this time create the record.

there are also 2 more dynamic possibilities:

1. you create the preview in real-time - if that is possible (like here on SO) - and use just the `create` action,
2. *a variation of the first option*: when the user submits the form, you send an *ajax post request* to a `preview` action, render a partial and include it on the page, then while your user still has the form he just filled, the user decides if she wants to modify or submit definitely.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest adding a DateTime column  "finished_at", "published_on", etc... whatever is appropriate for your domain.

Using blog posts as an example:

```
scope :published, where("published_on IS NOT NULL")
scope :draft, where(:published_on => nil)
```

Use the scopes and new field where appropriate to limit the follow up actions.

This approach gives you more than you asked for :

1. a way to limit processing based on "state"
2. Data on creation times versus publishing times

Comment: Yes -- while I admit the "blog post" domain doesn't relate very well to :users, the pattern still would work. The user could be created but not "available",  and the controller's create action could react accordingly.